# How do I add packages to go / golang in VS code?

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, go, path

Git hub gives instructions on how to install various packages to go.

But when I enter these in PowerShell, for example

```
go get -u github.com/disintegration/gift
```

I get a message

```
package github.com/disintegration/gift: exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

How do I add a package to path?

Comment: if you use go modules then system does that for you ... in your source dir issue  `go mod init` which will synthesize a file `go.mod` then anything you add to your import in your source code will get auto installed locally whenever you issue `go build` ...  see doc at  https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: What is my default source dir?

Comment: Same topic here ;) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044275/golang-go-get-command-showing-go-missing-git-command-error

Comment: Thank's.  I see PATHEXT, but not PATH, and I'm not sure what is meant by edit.  Also, does it matter what I name System Variables?

Comment: I added a variable path,that is set to /gin/bin/bash.exe and now it says that go is not recognized   go : The term 'go' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct    
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ go run main.go
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (go:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

`go get` uses git to fetch packages. You need to have git installed and add it to your %PATH%.

A tutorial on how to install git can be found [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-git-windows).

If you have any further questions, dont be afraid to ask.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks that showed me how and istall gift, but it didn't show me how to add it to %path%

Comment: Oh im sorry, I thought that the tutorial explained it to, but I seem to have remembered it incorrectly. Adding it to the %path% is relatively easy: [look here](https://www.answerlookup.com/how-add-git-windows-path-environment-variable). Be aware that the location of your git installation may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Install `git` or setup it properly (`PATH` and so) before trying to use `go`, as in `go get github.com/**`